# Express for NodeJS producing unexpected output on console

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, websocket, output

I have written a NodeJS backend using Express, connected it to a local instance of MongoDB using Mongoose and set up a WebSocket for communication with the frontend. Everything works fine, but I'm getting strange outputs on the commandline, like

```
<Buffer 22 22>
<Buffer 22 22>
<Buffer 22 22>
<Buffer 22 22>
<Buffer 22 22>
<Buffer 22 22>
<Buffer 22 22>
<Buffer 22 22>
```

and

```
<Buffer 7b 22 61 63 74 69 6f 6e 49 64 65 6e 74 69 66 69 65 72 22 3a 22 75 70 64 61 74 65 22 2c 22 62 6f 64 79 22 3a 7b 22 74 6f 22 3a 22 6d 69 74 61 72 62 65 ... 130 more bytes>
```

These messages seem to be triggered whenever my frontend makes a request to the backend, but I don't know what they mean and which part of my setup is producing them. Does anyone know what they are, what they mean, and how to fix (get rid of) them?

Comment: What you need to do is debugging. In your backend, place `console.log()` or any equivalent statements at different places in the area where you receive a request from the front end. Also, please provide a [mre] so that this issue can be replicated.

Comment: Well, I was hoping that someone here might have had similar issues and could point me in the right direction for debugging. And I don't think it's feasible to create a minimal reproducible example of a local DB setup and a full backend with several interacting services running...

Comment: Where is that `<Buffer..` logged? What is logged? Just try to back trace, where you get the data which is being logged.

Comment: Seems like a forgotten `console.log` statement. See through your code.

Comment: @Marc you were right! It really was just a console.log, which I never expected to log something similar to this. Thx!!